# Android IndexOutOfBounds Error on Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am developing an Android app with an Activity that loads data from DynamoDB into a Spinner. I set the Spinner by calling `employeeSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.employeeSpinner);`and I set its adapter and data by loading a list from DynamoDB like so:

```
final Context context = this;
    AsyncHandler<ScanRequest, ScanResult> asyncHandler = new AsyncHandler<ScanRequest, ScanResult>() {
        public void onError(Exception exception) {
            showDialogMessageAsync("Error", "Error scanning table: " + exception.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ScanRequest request, ScanResult result) {
            for (Map<String, AttributeValue> data : result.getItems()) {
                ConcurrentHashMap hashData = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(data);
                String orgName = (hashData.get(DynamoDBManager.ORGANIZATION_NAME)).toString();
                String employeeName = (hashData.get(DynamoDBManager.EMPLOYEE_NAME)).toString();
                Employee e = new Employee(orgName, employeeName);
                employeeList.add(e);
            }
            ArrayList<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<>();
            int length = employeeList.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                String name = employeeList.get(i).getEmployeeName();
                employeeNames.add(name);
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, employeeNames);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            employeeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
    };
    HashMap<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashMap<>();
    attributeValues.put(":orgName", new AttributeValue().withS(getOrgName()));
    String filterExpression = "organization_name = :orgName";
    DynamoDBManager.scan(asyncClient, DynamoDBManager.EMPLOYEE_TABLE, filterExpression, attributeValues, asyncHandler);
```

Here is the stack trace from the crash that occurs after the spinner is created:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=-1
                  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:349)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:405)
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:702)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:650)
                  at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:612)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

What I find particularly odd is that it says `index = -1`, but I don't do anything with my Spinner after creating it, so I'm not sure what would cause an attempt to access this index. The length appears to be the expected length of my list, however. What could be causing this?

Comment: I think you will find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917267/display-other-data-based-on-spinner-selection
"I was trying to setAdapter on spinner outside the ui thread. After wrapping the related code inside runOnUiThread, the issue is solved."

Comment: Thanks- this solved my problem. I tried to check for possible duplicates before posting my question but I didn't see that one.

Comment: I had to dig a little myself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Einar's comment solved my problem-all I had to do was wrap my code in runOnUiThread and the crash no longer occurred:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    employeeSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                }
            });
```